# Why do I get a invalid-hook error when I use a component from a umd library?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a simple Checkbox component which uses `useEffect` and `useState` to handle the checked state of the component.

I have added this component to my components collection (own project which contains all components). But if I want to use that Component in an other project i get the following error message: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321

The component works if I uncomment the `useState` and `useEffect` methods and it also works if I copy the whole component into my project (with the useEffect and useState methods!!)

I have tried the recommended solutions (https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html), but it didn't solve my problem.

```
const Checkbox = (props) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(props.checked); // initialize isChecked with the prop checked (true/false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.getCheckedState) {
      props.getCheckedState(isChecked); // to get the status of isChecked in my parent component
    }
  }, [isChecked]);

  return (
    //
    // My component
    //
  );
};

export {Checkbox};
```

Comment: `const Checkbox(props) {}` is not a valid function declaration... it should be `function Checkbox(props) {}`

Comment: or could be an arrow function: `const Checkbox = (props) => {}`

Comment: Sry it was my fail. It should be of course a arrow function. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you are using const and not the function keyword? try this:

```
export function Checkbox(props) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(props.checked); // initialize isChecked with the prop checked (true/false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.getCheckedState) {
      props.getCheckedState(isChecked); // to get the status of isChecked in my parent component
    }
  }, [isChecked]);

  return (
    //
    // My component
    //
  );
};
```

Comment: It makes no difference using function or arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying how are you actually do you import those hooks in the Checkbox component?

If Checkbox pulls one version of React and other project pulls a different version of React (for example the component which uses Checkbox imports different React) you perhaps are in the `You might have more than one copy of React in the same app` situation.

Ensure both Checkbox and other project import the same version of React.

Comment: Both projects use the same react and react-dom versions (16.8.6)

Comment: Hmm. Did you try the test in the docs: // Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

Comment: Even if versions are the same you might have two copies of it. This seems to me as a good hypothesis :-)